# TypeError: read_excel() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

Tags: python, python-2.7, pycharm

I get this problem when i try to read file:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

pos = pd.read_excel('pos.xls', header=None)
```

and the error is like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "one-hot.py", line 4, in <module>
pos = pd.read_excel('pos.xls', header=None)
TypeError: read_excel() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

but to my surprise,when i run the code in my own pc by pycharm,it will not be an error.i get the problem only when i use my school's ubuntu(not use pycharm).
my own python is python 2.7.12,and python on school's ubuntu is python 2.7.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best guess (I can't try it on `Python 2.7.6` since I don't have it) is that You use `pandas` version 0.13 or bellow. According to [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.13.1/generated/pandas.io.excel.read_excel.html), You must also provide `sheetname`, which, in later version, has default value of `0`.

```
pandas.io.excel.read_excel(io, sheetname, **kwds)
```

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like an issue with a different version of the `pandas` library installed. Looking back at the older documentation pages for `pandas` library, it seems that pandas did in fact require 2 parameters back in version 0.13.0 (and potentially other old versions, but I did not check any others). For version 0.13.0, the docs define the function as:

> pandas.read_excel(io, sheetname, **kwds)

You can read those details here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.13.0/generated/pandas.read_excel.html?highlight=read_excel#pandas.read_excel

Chances are, it is just an issue with a different library version.

Answer (score 0):

I actually had a similar problem which was solved by adding '.xlsx' to the end of my proposed file name:

`practicetoexcel.to_excel('Thisxldoc.xlsx', sheet_name = 'Practice')`